# Why ActiveRecord validates all columns of Model when use update_attributes or save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have password validation that its  length must be greater than 6;

```
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
```

it works when i save an object;

but it also work when i want to update the object like this:

```
model.update_attributes(key:value)
```

even i don't want to update password column

is this one of the rails rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behaviour.

[ActiveRecord::Persistence#`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update):

> Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves
>   the record, all wrapped in a transaction. ***If the object is invalid,
>   the saving will fail and false will be returned***.
>
> **Also aliased as: `update_attributes`**

To skip validation one of the options would be using [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute):

> Updates a single attribute and saves the record. This is especially
>   useful for boolean flags on existing records. Also note that
>
> Validation is skipped.
>
> Callbacks are invoked.
>
> `updated_at`/`updated_on` column is updated if that column is available.
>
> Updates all the attributes that are dirty in this object.
>
> This method raises an `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError` if the attribute
>   is marked as readonly.
>
> Also see `update_column`.

Another option is passing [`validate: false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations) as argument.

Comment: thank u ,but my password is valid when i create this object , why it is invalid when i update this object?

Comment: @junk I have no slightest clue. If Rails says it's invalid - it is invalid. See the error message it gives you. Maybe the password is weak.

Comment: @junk your question was about firing validation and I answered that :)

Comment: @junk Password is a virtual attribute so it will be nil unless you set value to the password attribute. When you call `model.password` it will return nil. If you don't want password to be validated then do a conditional validation for the password.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes i have, has_secure_password must skip  validates when update the object.

Comment: @junk if my answer was helpful in solving the issue make sure to checkmark it